# Best Practices Generics in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm wondering and actually playing in typescript playground with generics functions. The question is, is the code below readable? If not what kind of approach I could use to make it more typescript way and more readable?

Working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gGwCYJgVwHYGNgEs4YA8AKgHxQC8UAFAIYBcUxANFAEaPECUl5xA3AChBAM0w58GWIhQlS1EY3jJU4vATms2tAM4ROrWgCcjnANoBdLpygBvQVEdQsBHcChmAFhFpJWAOkCjCDcLSihjIyEnKGDgNCMpAEJvXygAfnZdaCUZBAVWEWptPVZUpC5WYLcuIQBfYRcMHUQIfwQ4AHNqZRRqOkYMNABbNggjLUGRsaMeCnI6KABqdkqoAAZWMwBGZgAmZgBmZgAWZm2D7bPtgFZzgDYrWuFQSCgAWXfaMHRsdSIWAAlchUAZMObkQFCURqSQfL5gEjMYEKRifb6-CQaIGkQwmcxWRiAyx2BxOJpuDzlAJBELAMJUSLRJxxBLJcoZDxhRhmIrlNaBfzosAFWJ0rgWeqNVytdpdajC-oADymo3GEJoSqgACooEq1jt9kdTudLtc7ttHlxnoJXtAYLgEMBxpj-nJwmDuLx2HBWrQMNCxH84Q6neM5KjYI7nUZXZJNBF8UxLNZk2F7DEKe4vD4-FBBdV6eEmWTHKzElAUrnOSTGKWYjQ%20bmeJkc74af5QzHRYWJVAeYKu%20Me%20KrIIGoIKbKOt0h0ZlaqZhrqFqAKRQPaUChUdYG3YHY7XM3nC1Wm24DAxkS0LDQAAK4xaUgzTgwtGG%20igbiMF86zMcOhsu%20n7fr%20-4RJ0n5DGqUTjtKzTuJARhPjojAPshBAklQZj1i%20DZQG%20H6MAA5AAUnAngYMRzD1jEgGJMBJEACJwBA1G0U4tCQYwJyHPWdQ0TEeENoRn7EQAymgABe-q0Ox%20EAUBRFQMRABCrFGPJClcZ%20ezbPxglOMJMSiSRd60GgCBafh9GmSpAAyEAYAQ1kNjpjAXPxgiSvBLQIG0M7UPWvT5HQWjLrQyyrKwmxQPWirULYOl1BFkFrMF0bDolyWpdAhAbjcaxISh1rWvwQA)

I implemented some basic functions like foldl, map and filter to experiment generics, maybe the implementation don't satisfies all requirements in the sense of functionality.

```js
type FoldlFunction<T> = (a: T, b: T) => T;

function Foldl<T>(f: FoldlFunction<T>, base: T, arr: T[]): T {
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return !head ? base : Foldl(f, f(base, head), rest);
}

console.log(Foldl((a: number, b: number) => (a + b), 0, [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16]));

type MMapFunction<T,R> = (a: T) => R;

function MMap<T,R>(f: MMapFunction<T,R>, arr: T[]): R[] {
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return !head ? [] : [f(head), ...MMap(f, rest)];
}

console.log(MMap((x: number) => (x * x), [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16]));

type FilterFunction<T> = (a: T) => boolean;

function Filter<T>(f: FilterFunction<T>, arr: T[]): T[] {
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return !head ? [] : 
        (f(head) ? [head, ...Filter(f, rest)] : [...Filter(f, rest)])
}

console.log(Filter((x: number) => (x % 2 === 0), [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16]));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks quite reasonable, though there are a few tweaks you could consider.

**Function or Callback?** Rather than names like `FoldlFunction` and `MMapFunction`, since what those types contain are the types for the *callback* run for each element of the array, consider calling them `FoldlCallback` etc instead. It's a bit more precise and will make more intuitive sense at a glance. (One might think at a glance that `FoldlFunction` might refer to the type of the whole `Foldl` function, which is incorrect.)

**`camelCase`** is the near-universal convention for plain non-class functions and variables in JavaScript. PascalCase is generally used for class constructors and namespaces, which aren't being used here, so camelCase is probably more appropriate. Eg `Foldl` -> `foldl` (or to `foldL`).

**DRYer types** You only need to specify the type of a parameter when TypeScript can't infer it automatically. For example, with `foldl`, since the base value is T, and the array is `T[]`, the callback - the `f: FoldlFunction<T>` - will be known to be of the form `(a: T, b: T) => T`. There's no need to additionally specify the arguments' types when calling `foldl`. That is, this:

```
foldl((a: number, b: number) => (a + b), 0, [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16])
```

can be

```
foldl((a, b) => (a + b), 0, [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16])
```

It's a good idea to let TypeScript automatically infer the types of variables and parameters whenever possible - less code to read makes comprehension easier. You can do the same thing for `MMap` and `Filter`.

**Outside definition?** I'm not entirely convinced of defining the type of the function/callback outside - it's one more type parameter that needs to be cognitively pieced together. Consider defining the callback type in the parameter list:

```
function foldl<T>(
    f: (a: T, b: T) => T,
    base: T,
    arr: T[]
): T {
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return !head ? base : foldl(f, f(base, head), rest);
}

console.log(foldl((a, b) => (a + b), 0, [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16]));
```

I consider that significantly more readable. You can do the same thing for `MMap` and `Filter`.

**Falsey bug** You use `return !head ? base : foldl...`. This will not run if `head` is falsey. For example, `foldl((a, b) => (a + b), 0, [1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16])` results in 67, but `foldl((a, b) => (a + b), 0, [0, 1,2,3,4,12,14,15,16])` results in 0, which probably isn't desirable. Check the array's length instead:

```
function foldl<T>(
    f: (a: T, b: T) => T,
    base: T,
    arr: T[]
): T {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return base;
    }
    const [head, ...rest] = arr;
    return foldl(f, f(base, head), rest);
}
```

This applies to `MMap` and `Filter` as well.

**DRYer filter** To fix the falsey bug *and* make Filter a bit cleaner, you can replace:

```
const [head, ...rest] = arr;
return !head ? [] : 
    (f(head) ? [head, ...Filter(f, rest)] : [...Filter(f, rest)])
```

with

```
if (!arr.length) {
  return [];
}
const includeThis = f(head); // call this here to preserve callback execution order
const restFiltered = Filter(f, rest);
return includeThis ? [head, ...restFiltered] : restFiltered;
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer, as a beginner in typescript I really thought that will be good practice to put types explicitly everywhere, good to know that I can trust typescript to infer obvious code by itself.

Comment: Other question that arises in my mind, is if it is possible to "extract" the type of an function parameter, for example, you said that the outside definition was not quite relevant in this example, but suppose I want to extract the type of f parameter of foldl will it be possible? I don't know if I make myself understandable, but I know that I can "extract" the type of an object property using keyof right, is there some operator that could help me do the same thing with a function parameter?

Comment: You can use `Parameters`, eg `type Callback = Parameters<typeof f>;` or `Parameters<typeof foldl>[0];`

Comment: Something interesting just happens, I think as typescript cannot infer the contextual type, when I do something like you suggested`type Callback = Parameters<typeof foldl>[0]` the signature of Callback is `(a: unknown, b: unknown): unknown` as demonstrated here in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAgNgE3QHgCoB8AFCAFzJECG5eANMgEY0CUyAvAcnY5QM4CmNepQBOImgG0AusxrIA3sGTLkUJLxjIJAC36VM9AHTGR-DVPbJRIgNxKVpmGBEoAhLv3IA-DwHJyaFjoJPQgRAx8-PQemMz0phrMdgC+wMAwAJ4ADvzIAMKU6OgRUADWlgAKopQAtvww-CK8OJk5CCCoGNgEEgAMUmlAA) how could I use generics in Callback definition?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going on there. It could be that if the callback type is inlined like that, it can't be extracted outside the function. It can be used *inside* the function: `type Callback = typeof f;` If you need the type outside the function, you can declare it outside as well like your original code does with `type FoldlFunction<T> = (a: T, b: T) => T;`.

Comment: I’m not sure callback is much better; functional programming simply calls those parameters « functions »